# Size of unity game increases when integrated with IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have developed a game in unity and its size is 6 MB but when I integrate it with IOS through X-Code its size increases to 160 MB after deployment.

What may be the problem with the size?
Is there any way to decrease it?

Comment: So what you mean is that (.apk = 6mb and .ipa = 160mb) ?

Comment: @Hristo when the game is integrated with ios the size of .ipa is 48 MB (its ok). but when it is uploaded to apple store then size shown there is 160 MB. and when we download it in iphone the downloaded file is 181 MB.

Comment: and apk is 6mb? how did you do that, my apks are at least 18mb extra of what my assets are

Comment: @Lestat the build from unity is 6 MB not the apk or ipa

Comment: What is the apk size, have you optimised the sprites, textures. Check build settings if development build option is checked!

Comment: @rohankad sorry i can't get you as i am new in the field. Can you please explain a bit more

Comment: hope that it will help you https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-x-build-size-increase-faq.383533/

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Can you give me any other solution. The one you provided did not help.

Comment: can you check editor log after build it will precisely tell you anything about your build

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan after the ipa is created. The file named "App Thinning Size Report" says that the compressed size is 19 MB (after following the solution you provided) and uncompressed size is still 159 MB

Comment: sorry the final thing i only know https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html

Comment: @ihsanKhan Which unity version you are using? Can you build it with the new version of unity?

Comment: @rohankad i am using unity version 5.6

Comment: Related question from today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323860/xcode-8-3-makes-exceptionally-large-ipa-file-for-unity-ios-build

Answer (score 0):

By setting Enable Bitcode to NO in project build settings -> select all from menu and under the section Build option decreased the size a little bit but the problem is still there.

Comment: why is this marked as solution if it didnt solve your problem?